# How to reason about independence of combinations of events?

Tags: independence, conditional-independence

Suppose sets $A , B,$ and $D$ are independent.  Is it guaranteed that  $A \cap B^c \cap D$  is independent from  $B^c \cup D^c$?

Isn't $B^c$ ($B$ complement, or $B$ not happening) giving me information about $B^c \cup D^c$? (A) I know that $B$ complement happened so it should increase the chances of $B^c \cup D^c$ happening, thus they are not independent.

Is my statement (A) correct?

Comment: Hint: What is the set $(A\cap B^c\cap D)\,\cap\,(B^c\cup D^c)$?  I believe you can simplify this expression.  Drawing a Venn diagram may be helpful.

Comment: I found that the intersection is empty. Is that right?If so, this would mean that they are dependent? Because they are disjoint events.

Comment: Any element that is in $A$ and $D$ but not in $B$ lies in this set.

Comment: But to intersect it should be outside D, so D and Dc never intersect , right?

Comment: You have forgotten that $B^c\cup D^c$ includes elements of $B^c,$ which may be in $D.$  The Venn diagram will make this clear.

Comment: Hum, I see, B complement intersects  (A∩Bc∩D) but D complement doesn't. The new Venn diagram with Bc∪Dc  doesn't change, so it doesn't add new information, thus B complement doesn't clarify if they are independent from each other, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inspiration, **let's examine Venn diagrams of each set.**

Elements of $\mathcal{X}=A\cap B^c\cap D$ are (a) in $A;$ (b) *not* in $B;$ and (c) in $D$.  This region is highlighted in yellow.

[image: Figure 1]

Elements of $\mathcal{Y}=B^c\cup D^c$ are either not in $B$ or not in $D$ (or both).  This includes a lot of the diagram, so instead I have highlighted its *complement* -- namely, everything that is *not* in this set.  The complement of $\mathcal Y$ is $B\cap D$ (this evident equality is one of [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

[image: Figure 2]

Now, two sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal Y$ are independent [if and only if](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/303955/919) $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}^c$ are independent.  But since $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}^c$ are disjoint, the probability of their intersection is zero.  When both $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal{Y}^c$ have nonzero probability, the rule for independence won't hold.

**From this insight we may construct an example** where the two sets $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$ are not independent.  (Once we have found this example, we needn't repeat any of the foregoing analysis: the example alone is enough to resolve the problem.  But I thought you might want to understand how such examples can be cooked up and what kind of thinking goes into that.)

For this example I will put one element into $\mathcal{X}$ and one into $\mathcal{Y}^c:$ since neither $\mathcal X$ nor $\mathcal{Y}^c$ can be empty, yet are disjoint, that's as simple as an example possibly could be.

Looking at the two diagrams, then, let's put (say) the number $0$ into $A$ and $D$ but not $B$ and (say) the number $1$ into both $B$ and $D.$  One way to do this is to define

$$A = \{0\},\quad B = D = \{1\}.$$

Define a probability measure for $A\cup B \cup D = \{0,1\}$ by giving $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ equal chances of $1/2.$  Note that *any set in this probability space can have probability $0,$ $1/2,$ or $1,$ but no other value is possible.*   Here's a Venn diagram showing the set elements:

[image: Figure 3]

Computing

$$\Pr(\mathcal{X}) = \Pr(A\cap B^c\cap D) = \Pr(\{0\}) = \frac{1}{2},$$

$$\Pr(\mathcal{Y}) = \Pr(B^c\cup D^c) = \Pr(\{0\}) = \frac{1}{2},$$

we see that the independence of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ would mean (by definition)

$$\Pr(\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}) = \Pr(\mathcal{X})\Pr(\mathcal{Y}) = \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Since a probability of $1/4$ is impossible, $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ cannot be independent.

Comment: Also since Pr(X) = Pr(Y) is different from Pr(X and Y), events are dependent.BTW Thank you, Whuber.

Comment: Correct.  But I didn't have to compute $\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}$ :-).