# How to determine if two events are independent or not?

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

I have this question on an ungraded practice test.

The possible outcomes of an experiment are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and assume that all of the outcomes are equally likely. Let A be the event that the result is odd, and let B be the event that the result is less than 4. Calculate P(A and B). Round your answer to 3 decimal places.

Here's how I went about solving it:

P(A) = 4/8 = 1/2
P(B) = 3/8

P(A and B) = P(A)*P(B) = (1/2) * (3/8) = 3/16

However the correct answer is 0.25. Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's because P(A and B) = P(A)P(B) works only when A and B are *independent*, are you familiar with that term?

Comment: Yes, that's when the probability of two events is not dependent on each other.

Comment: Since there are two odd numbers less than 4, and only one even number, we can see that once we know the number is less than 4, the probability of A becomes bigger so A and B are not independent. Without independence, one way to solve this problem is simply to add together the probabilities of the odd numbers less than 4.

Comment: You cannot use formula $P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A)P(B)$ unless you first prove that $A$ and $B$ are independent events. In this case, it turns out that they are not independent. The simplest way to answer is to explicitly remark that $A = \{1,3,5,7\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$, and thus $A \text{ and } B = A \cap B = \{1,3\}$; so $P(A \cap B) = 2 / 8 = 0.25.$

Comment: How is this a question about _union_ at all?  Please edit the _title_ of your question.

Comment: For some reason it's hard for me to tell whether two events are independent or not. Is there a process you use to tell?

Comment: Yes: check the definition.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303753.  In your case you could draw a diagram of the sample space like this: $$\begin{array}{cccc}
1\ & 3\ \mid &  5 & 7 \\ \hline
2\ \mid & 4 & 6 & 8
\end{array}$$ There are four odd numbers with probability $4/8,$ three numbers less than $4$ (with probability $3/8$) and two in *both* sets (which is called their *intersection*) with probability $2/8.$  All you have to do is check whether $4/8\times 3/8=2/8.$